# Is it possible to reference data in other nodes in firebase security rules using wildcards?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I know it's possible to reference in the same node using wildcards :

```
statistics: {
     "$uid" : {
          ".read": "($uid === auth.uid)"
      }
}
```

But, what if I have to add a reference to some other nodes using wildcards, something like :

```
statistics: {
  .read = "root.child('users').child(//wildcard for unique ids).child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to check if there's any node in the `users` collection that has the `uid` of the user. This is not possible. Security rules can only access specific nodes, they cannot search for them.

The typical solution is to add an inverted collection, where the `uid`s are the keys:

```
usersByUid
  <uid1>: ...
  <uid2>: ...
```

With such a structure, you can check for the existence of the key with:

```
.read = "root.child('usersByUid').child(auth.uid).exists()"
```

In general it is recommended to store users under their `uid` and not under some other key.

Comment: thank you for the response. I added a separate node in firebase and added the uids as keys as you have suggested.